# How to convert hex string to hex number in nodejs

Tags: string, numbers, hex

I have:
`"#ffd900"` in string and I would like to convert to number `0xffd900`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must remove the first character and then convert to int using the `parseInt` function

`parseInt(a.split("#")[1],16)`